# Uninstalling of the app doesn't erase the value of SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have used SharedPreferences to check whether it is already logged in or not. But after I logged in and then uninstall the app, it always gives true value while reinstalling the app and login page is not shown. Why is it? Isn't it true that when the app is uninstalled, the value in sharedPreference should have gone too? It works in unsigned apk (ie when you install the app directly through android studio) but as soon as I use signed apk, the problem appears. It is happening in nokia 5 and some other devices but works perfectly fine in other android devices. How can I solve it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        **//always gives true value here...**
        Log.e("loginStatus", pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false) + "");
        if (pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)) {
            Log.e("loginStatus", pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false) + "");

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LiveTrack.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Log.e("loginStatus", "notlogin");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May be the problem with Instant Run. Turn Off instant run and check, Every time your building a signed apk it is better to clean the build

Comment: share code where you are setting true value flag for login

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the problem with some of the devices.Try deleting the data files manually when user quits the app.

```
File sharedPreferenceFile = new File("/data/data/"+ getPackageName()+ "/shared_prefs/");
File[] listFiles = sharedPreferenceFile.listFiles();
for (File file : listFiles) {
    file.delete();
}
```

Also make sure you havent turned on the allowBackup as true because from android-23 by default backup stores app's data including preferences to cloud.Later when you uninstall then reinstall newer version you will to use restored preferences.

```
<application ...
    android:allowBackup="false">
</application>
```

Comment: wifi and data..i think anyone of the two should work

Comment: How we know app is uninstalling and call this methods?

Comment: If you want to delete files programatically you need to add that method somewhere like in logout button or somewhere.

Comment: You do not have to delete the files yourself. The files get deleted at uninstall. Its a pitty that Anonymous mentioned this as the second part of his post will be that what happens.

Comment: R u sure?if you dont know then dont comment."/data/data/".Android deletes "/Android/data/" on uninstalling of the app

Comment: And I am sure allowBackup is causing the preference to restore back when installing app again

Comment: @Anonymous thanks.. allowBackup="false" works. Does it have any consequences if I set it as false since by default it is true.

Comment: @amritha Stha i suggest you to keep the allowBackup=true as backup includes other data than sharedpreferences..it also includes othr files tht you create inside the app such files created using getFilesDir()...you can exclude sharedpreferences from the xml file that is created for managing the backup..for more info and clear understanding check this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html